# Docker mongo-express cannot connect to mongo if started with /data/db volume

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a docker-compose.yml which I start with `docker-compose up` — and it works.

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017-27019:27017-27019
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: brandRegistry
    volumes:
      - ./setup/init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
      # - ./data/mongo-volume:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

But if I comment `- ./data/mongo-volume:/data/db` in the log says:

```
mongo-express_1  | Tue Jan 28 22:21:16 UTC 2020 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (4/5)
mongo-express_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
mongo-express_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
```

I do not see how this relates to the volume...
I would like to store persistent data. Do you have a tip?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because `mongo-express` depends on `mongo` which is mounted to that volume.

Comment: @arilwan I don't quite understand. But I found the solution....I just did not wait long enough. Mongo needs way longer if started with a data volume outside of the container. And mongo-express will try to connect again after a while until it works.

Answer (score 1):

I just did not wait long enough. Mongo needs way longer if started with a data volume outside of the container. And mongo-express will try to connect again and again. After a while it will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to mongo-express configuration on docker-compose.yaml [or how ever you named the file]

restart: unless-stopped

mongo-express will restart , until mongo container is ready, and when it is ready it will connect and stay up.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The answer had already been solved. But the restart option is a good hint.